# How to add a text below a table image exported by Panda dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe

How would i go about addding some texts below a table using Panda dataframe?
I want to put my text just under my table so in this case which could i do?
[image exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrj5d.png)
I tried to position my text but it doesn't work.
I also tried to make 2 subplots ,one for the table and one for its legend box but then i can't remove the blank space between 2 subplots.
Heres my code:

```
    def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                 header_color='dodgerblue', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                 bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                 ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        figi = plt.figure(figsize=size)
        ax=figi.add_subplot(2,1,1)
        ax.axis('off')


        note_legend=figi.add_subplot(2,1,2)
        note_legend.axis([0,100,0,100]) 
        note_legend.axis('off')

        l0='A*: Acier rompu'          
        l1='B*: Béton écrasé' 
        l2='C*: Cadre rompu'    
        l3='T*: Torseurs trop importants'
        l4='S*: Contraintes supplémentaires torsion/tranchant trop importantes'
        l5='R*: Combinaison torsion/tranchant non vérifiée'
        l6="V*: Résistance à l'effort tranchant de la section non suffisante"
        texte=(l0+'\n'+l1+'\n'+l2+'\n'+l3+'\n'+l4+'\n'+l5+'\n'+l6+'\n')
        note_legend.text(0,-2,texte,fontsize=11,family='monospace',style='italic')


    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)
    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

    for k, cell in  six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
                cell.set_text_props(style='italic',weight='medium',size='large',color='w')
                cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        else:
                cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors)])    
        if k[0]==0 and (k[1]==3 or k[1]==4 or k[1]==5 or k[1]==6):  
                cell.set_text_props(weight='bold',size='large',color='w')

    return ax

render_mpl_table(df, header_columns=0, col_width=2.0)
```

It give me this:[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2azO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that a solution which would require the least changes to the current code would be one that creates subplots of different height.

```
fig, (ax,note_legend)  = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=size, 
                                      gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios = [0.8,0.2]))
ax.axis('off')
note_legend.axis([0,100,0,100]) 
note_legend.axis('off')
```

The above would produce the axes for the table with 80% of the available space and the axes for the legend with 20% of the available space. You would still need to adjust those parameters to fit your actual data though.

Comment: i tried your solution but it sent me an error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sect.py", line 854, in <module>
    render_mpl_table(df, header_columns=0, col_width=2.0)
  File "Sect.py", line 819, in render_mpl_table
    fig,(ax,note_legend)  = plt.subplots(figsize=size,gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios = [0.8,0.2]))                           
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable

Comment: Yes there is an `nrows=2` missing, because you need two subplots.